# Call a Redshift stored procedure with a parameter from lambda boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, boto3

I have a stored proc that I want to call from my AWS lambda. The value of the parameter will change with each invocation which is why it cannot be hardcoded (to state the obvious).

From the boto3 documentation I believe that this is the way to do it:

```
response = rs_client.execute_statement(
            ClusterIdentifier='my_cluster_name',
            Database='my_db_name',
            DbUser='my_user'',
            Sql='call my_schema.this_is_my_proc()',
            Parameters=[{'name': 'in_param', 'value': 'this is the parameter'}],
            StatementName='Test of SP call'
        )
```

but I get this error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Parameters list contains unused parameters. Unused parameters: [in_param]
```

I can call it with a hardcoded parameter which works but is of course pointless (but proves that the call to the proc works):

```
Sql="call my_schema.this_is_my_proc('and this is the parameter')"
```

For completeness my stored proc heading looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure my_schema.this_is_my_proc(in_param varchar)
as $$
declare
...
```

Is it possible to call a Redshift SP with one or more parameters from a lambda using boto3?

Edit - the Parameter argument would look something like this:

```
Parameter=[{'name': 'in_param', 'value': a_variable}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You've given it a parameter named `in_param` but you haven't told it where that parameter goes. The Data API doesn't look up and match the names of parameters with the names in the stored procedure definition. This feature has to work with other types of SQL commands that don't have named parameters. It's really just a basic string substitution that is happening.

As per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html), you need to add parameter placeholders in your SQL. Like this:

```
Sql='call my_schema.this_is_my_proc(:in_param)',
Parameters=[{'name': 'in_param', 'value': 'this is the parameter'}],
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Python as your Lambda language you can solve this problem by also using the psycopg2 package instead of the boto3 package as below:

```
import psycopg2
import sys

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=sys.argv[1], host=sys.argv[2], port=sys.argv[3], user=sys.argv[4], password=sys.argv[5])
cur = conn.cursor()
in_param="myname"
cmd = f"CALL my_procedure_name('{in_param}');"
cur.execute(cmd)
conn.commit()
```

Note: Since Aws Lambda doesn't have out-of-box support for psycopg2, therefore merely using `import psycopg2` inside your python code won't help. You will also need to package this psycopg2 folder along with your own Python code file inside a zip file and upload that zip file as your Lambda source code. I downloaded my psycopg2 binaries from this location for my Python 3.7 version from [here](https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2) . You can download your python version compatible psycopg2 folder from this same link and bundle it with your own Python source code file and create the desired zip file.